# find and replace .htaccess code

Tags: linux, bash, replace, find, centos

I want to **find** and **remove** code in all .htaccess files and directories under **/home** directory

```
RedirectMatch \.(dynamiccontent|pl|plx|perl|cgi|php|php4|php4|php6|php3|shtml)$ http://domain.com/cgi-sys/movingpage.cgi
```

What is the bash command to do this job ?

edit:

i tried this command

```
find /home*/*/public_html/ -mindepth 1 -iname "\.htaccess" -type f -exec grep -Hi "RedirectMatch*" '{}' \;
```

but this command find only the code , not remove it , also the code find all redirectmatch code not the specific code i mention at the first of my question

Comment: You want to remove all `RedirectMatch` lines?

Comment: no i want to remove this line only , there is another redirectmatch codes in other .htaccess i don't want to remove all redirectmatch code , but this one only

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak '/RedirectMatch \\\.(dynamiccontent/d' .htaccess
```

Comment: this is work to remove the code very well but how can i excute both command find and remove the code in one command ?

Comment: This is actually doing find and replacement in single command because of `-i` switch.

Comment: find /home*/*/public_html/ -mindepth 1 -iname "\.htaccess" -type f -exec sed -i.bak '/RedirectMatch \\\.(dynamiccontent/d' {} \;